# Can Mathematica check spelling during typing?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, options, editing

I can't see a way to get *Mathematica* to check my spelling as I type. Is this feature not supported? I've done everything I can think of with my options:

[image]

Is there a setting I'm missing?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken this syntax colouring is only for Input Cells.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch: So is there no "while you type" spelling error highlighting for basic text?!

Comment: Not AFAIK ...but there is so much in Mathematica that I do not know. Someone else may know of this if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

This is *almost* a solution:

```
Module[{str},
 checkPrevWord[char_] := (
   SelectionMove[nb, Previous, Word];
   SelectionMove[nb, All, Word];
   str = StringJoin[
     StringCases[NotebookRead[nb] /. StyleBox[a_, b___] :> a, 
      RegularExpression["\\w"]]];
   If[StringLength[str] =!= 0 && 
      Length[DictionaryLookup[str, IgnoreCase -> True]] === 0, 
     SetOptions[NotebookSelection[nb], FontColor -> Red]; 
     SelectionMove[nb, Next, Word];
     SetOptions[NotebookSelection[nb], FontColor -> Black],
     SetOptions[NotebookSelection[nb], FontColor -> Black];
     SelectionMove[nb, Next, Word]
     ]
    NotebookWrite[nb, char];);

 SetOptions[nb =  CreateDocument[], 
  NotebookEventActions -> ({"KeyDown", #} :> 
       checkPrevWord[#] & /@ {" ", ";", ".", "-", "!", "?", ",", "/"})];
 ]
```

I create a new notebook and check if the previous word you typed is in the dictionary (English).  Unfortunately, I do not know how to test for being in a `TextCell` versus any other `Cell`, so the spell-checker will try to check the code too.  Also, (**BEWARE**), this crashes Mathematica if you delete your text cell.

Note that you can replace `CreateDocument` with `SelectedNotebook` if you want to affect the current notebook.

Hopefully someone can help me identify what I'm missing, and then we'll have a spell-highlighter.

Comment: So does this mean that *Mathematica*, unlike every other text editing tool on the planet, doesn't have as-you-type spellchecking?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius None that I know of.  However, it does seem to be implementable.  I don't think Wolfram had Microsoft Word in mind when MMA was being made.